# Oracle Fusion - Advance Mode Journal Approval rule - Looping Requirement

Tags: oracle-fusion-apps

We have a requirement where the journal should be balanced by Legal Entity (Account Segment 1) & wherever there is an imbalance, that journal should be rejected.

For this requirement, we have used Advance mode in Journal Approval rule in BPM.

We have been successfully able to create a rule for this, but the issue in this rule is that

we were only able to check this for a single Account Segment1 i.e. "001".

The name of the rule is AdvanceRuleTest. Screenshot of this rule is attached here for reference.(Change the extension to ".docx")

I am looking for a way to loop the whole rule for All the Legal Entities i.e. Account Segment1.

Please let me know if there is a way in BPM which can handle this requirement.

I tried using "Each" function in Advance mode, but still not sure how to make it loop for all the BSVs.